# Use of "-w" in the shebang line

Tags: perl

I am new to perl scripting and I am wondering what is the use of "-w" in hashbang of perl scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $userid = $ENV{USER};
print "$userid\n";
```

I know that this part `#!/usr/bin/perl` is used to inform shell that it is a perl script so that no need to use `perl` before running the script.
But I couldn't find the exact meaning for `-w` and most of the scripts I saw have this option .
Kindly let me know if that has any significance as I could not find any difference.

**Edit:**
Below document is very helpful(Suggested by @Toto)
https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perlrun.html

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perlrun.html

Comment: See [man perl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything after the command is passed as arguments to the command being invoked.

The `-w` option to the `perl` command is to enable warnings.